# How to implement 3 popups using jquery AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have 3 selects on my page. Once an item is selected, that value is used to populate the next select box. I'm using a jquery ajax function to do this.

In "addfaq.php", I have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#product').on('change', function() {  
    var sel = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
    $.ajax({
        url: "addfaq_process.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {prod : sel},
        success: function(data) {
            $( ".divproduct" ).html(data);
        }
    });
}); 

$('#topic').on('change', function() {  
    var sel = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
    $.ajax({
        url: "addfaq_process.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {topic : sel },
        success: function(data) {
            $( ".divtopic" ).html(data);
        }
    });
}); 

$('#subtopic').on('change', function() {  
    var sel = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
    $.ajax({
        url: "addfaq_process.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {subtopic : sel},
        success: function(data) {
            $( ".divsubtopic" ).html(data);
        }
    });
}); 
});
```

My problem is that I don't know where to put the `<option><select></select></option>` statements. If I put them in "addfaq_process.php", the onchange doesn't fire off since it's located in "addfaq.php".  If I put them in "addfaq.php", I'm not sure how to get the information (I populated an array of menu values) into "addfaq_process.php". A simple echo statement just prints the array values but I need the values to be formatted in a menu.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Those are called SELECT BOXES, not pop-ups.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have to review your architecture. Try centralizing html and js to one place and then fire off specific ajax calls to get specific data from the server.

From your description it seems like you want to display certain data depending on user interaction.

One way to do it is listening to changes on select elements:

```
<select id="first_option"> 
   <option>foo</option>
</select>
```

**js**

```
$("#first_option").change(function(e){
     //Fire ajax with the current value 
      $.post('db.php',function(data){
      //Do something with returned data
       }
})
```

You should then have a php file that accesses your database and sends it (You can simply `echo` the info for this) and use the success method in your JS side to render it correctly.